# Visual Studio Typescript Multiple Module systems

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015

Is it possible to have different typescript build configurations for different folders of typescript code using Visual Studio's Typescript build?

Answer (score 0):

> Visual Studio's Typescript build

No. Honestly, you will have a hard time setting that up with most build tools. I recommend using `commonjs` everywhere e.g checkout https://github.com/alm-tools/alm/blob/master/src/tsconfig.json < single tsconfig for both backend / frontend.